# How to get the item's index of a JPopupMenu selection?

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PopupMenuSelectedIndex extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  JPopupMenu popup;

  public PopupMenuSelectedIndex() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(450, 260);
//  Create the popup menu.
    popup = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
    menuItem.addActionListener(this);
    popup.add(menuItem);
    JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Item 2");
    menuItem2.addActionListener(this);
    popup.add(menuItem2);
    setVisible(true);
    popup.show(this, 100, 100);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(PopupMenuSelectedIndex::new);
  }


  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
    System.out.println(source.getText());
    int ind= popup.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
//    int ind= popup.getComponentIndex(source); // This one works.
    System.out.println(ind);
  }

}
```

This code shows always -1 as selected index. What am I missing?

One could achive the goal with
`int ind= popup.getComponentIndex(source);` but I still would like to know, how to handle the SelectionModel.

Comment: I would guess there is no selection since the popup is closed. Try adding a ListSelectionListener to the popup to see if you get selection events when the popup is visible.

Comment: Thank you, Camickr. Your suggestion sounds reasonable. Still I clould not implement a ListSelectionListener with simple means. Probably one has to extend the JPopup class, which is not worth the effort as the goal can be reached with one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of your PopupMenu isn't showing. There Are no selection and `popup.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();` return -1